# Created not being triggered in Vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I'm implementing an application with Vue Js and I've the following code:

```
<template>
    <simple-page title="list-patient" folder="Patient" page="List Patient" :loading="loading">
        <list-patients @patientsLoaded="onPatientsLoaded"/>
    </simple-page>
</template>
```

Both simple-page and list-patients are custom components created by me. Inside ListPatients I've an HTTP request on Create callback, as follows:

```
created() {
        axios.get("...").then(response => {
            ...
            this.$emit('patientsLoaded');
        })
 },
```

Then, my objective is to handle the patientsLoaded event and uptade the loading prop on the top parent component, as follows:

```
data() {
        return {
            loading: true
        }
    },   
methods: {
        onPatientsLoaded(params) {
            this.loading = false;
        }
    }
```

However, the created method is not being triggered inside the list-patients component. The only way I can make this work is by removing :loading.
Any one can help?

**Edit 1**
Code of simple page:

```
<template>
<section :id="id">
    <!-- Breadcrumb-->
    <breadcumb :page="page" :folder="folder"/>
    <!-- Breadcrumb-->
    <!-- Simple Card-->
    <simple-card :title="page" :icon="icon" :loading="loading" v-slot:body>
        <slot>

        </slot>
    </simple-card>
    <!-- Simple Card-->
</section>
</template>
```

Code of simple card:

```
<b-card>
    <!-- Page body-->
    <slot name="body" v-if="!loading">

    </slot>
    <!--Is loading-->
    <div class="loading-container text-center d-block">
        <div v-if="loading" class="spinner sm spinner-primary"></div>
    </div>
</b-card>
```

Comment: What does :loading props do in you component? Maybe it simply disables slot with your list-patients and because of that its lifecycle hooks will never fire. Providing code for simple-page component could help to clear things up.

Comment: Hi @BrainOverflow. I've just updated the code with the remaining components. Best regards

Answer (score 1):

Your list-patients component goes in the slot with name "body". That slot has a v-if directive so basically it is not rendered and hooks are not reachable as well. Maybe changing v-if to v-show will somehow help you in that situation. Anyway, you have deeply nested slots and it is making things messy. I usually declare loading variable inside of the component, where fetching data will be rendered.
For example:

```
data () {
  return {
    loading: true;
  };
},
mounted() {
  axios.get('url')
    .then(res => {
      this.loading = false;
    })
}
```

and in your template:

```
<div v-if="!loading">
  <p>{{fetchedData}}</p>
</div>
<loading-spinner v-else></loading-spinner>
```

idk maybe that's not best practise solution

Answer (score 0):

1. `v-slot` for named slots can be indicated in `template` tag only
2. I suppose you wished to place passed default slot as `body` slot to `simple-card` component? If so you should indicate v-slot not in `simple-card` itself but in a content you passed it it.

```
<simple-card :title="page" :icon="icon" :loading="loading">
  <template v-slot:body>
    <slot>
    </slot>
  </template>
</simple-card>
```

Answer (score 0):

Enable vue 3 Options API:

```
// vue.config.js
chainWebpack: config => {        
    config.plugin('feature-flags').tap(args => {
      args[0].__VUE_OPTIONS_API__ = JSON.stringify(true);
      args[0].__VUE_PROD_DEVTOOLS__ = JSON.stringify(false);
      args[0].__VUE_PROD_HYDRATION_MISMATCH_DETAILS__ = JSON.stringify(false);
      return args
    })
```